How to work with (Zip)FileSystems - keep open or re-open as needed?
I'm working on a project with Java 8. The component I'm working on provides access to files, e.g. config files, that are classpath resources.
It's my first time working with nio.file.Pathand nio.file.FileSystem. I've looked up several things online, but what I can't figure out is how to handle FileSystems correctly, because to access a file using Path the `FileSystem´ must be/remain open.
The overall use case is that several consumers can request the same or different config files at any time. The access to a file resource will be provided using a Path that is a member of a MyResource object.
This is a rough draft of how a Path is created atm.
Path getResource(fileNameStr) {
  Path result = null;

  URI uri =  ClassLoader.getSystemResource(fileNameStr).toURI();

  Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
  env.put("create", "true");

  FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri);
  result = Paths.get(uri);

  // question: close zipfs or keep open?

  return result;
}

What I would like to understand: Can a (Zip)FileSystem remain open to ease further working with a Path instance and e.g. needed InputStreams? Or should it always be closed and later "reloaded" when a file will actually be read.
My assumption is that keeping multiple ZipFileSystems open indefinitely is not intended, but not keeping them open means that consumers must always check if a needed ZipFileSystem already exist and if not, they must create one. Also the closing of a ZipFileSystem must be managed if several consumers access the same JAR simultaneously . It would be possible for me to add further functionalities to ease the file access, but I'd assume if that is needed, it would already exist. Therefore there must be an answer/process of working with (Zip)FileSystems I'm not understanding yet.

For your question the Java version doesn't matter. If you should keep the zip file opened or not depends on how often you access it if it is (un)desired to keep the ZIP file "locked" (on Windows opened files by default ran not be deleted, overwritten or renamed this may be desired, not relevant or totally undesired).

Thank you @Robert. The files are part of our java environment and will not be touched in any way as long as the process is running. / Do you by any chance have a suggestion or link to a resource/example om how to handle opening/closing a FileSystems when several consumers in the process could be using it. I would like to gain a general understanding.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Adding some code refs 1 , 2, 3 as food for thought for people trying to find an answer.

May be you need a caching mechanism for FileSystem instances that should remain opened for subsequent use, and/or add a count to track the number of consumers/users of the file, once it is 0 (or the file no longer used) you can close it

I've changed the method getResource() to use URI instead of Path as return type. This way it remains flexible and works great in the context of my use cases.

Although this is a workaround, I wouldn't consider this an actual answer to the question you asked.

Yes, you are right. Should the answer flag be removed?

It's your prerogative to accept an answer, though maybe without having accepted an answer, it's possible that someone searching for "unanswered" questions shows an interest later on. In any case, I have added a bounty to see if it draws a more specific answer.
